# Cannot fill CGContext for simple shape

Tags: cgcontext, fill

The following method should create a FILLED triangle image but it only creates an outline.
Why does it not FILL? Going bonkers with this one. I hope it gets answered so that the next poor soul struggling with this can clear the hurdle and save an hour of their life.

Here is the method I wrote:

```
+ (UIImage *)triangleWithSize:(CGSize)imageSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);

    // set parameters
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);

    // draw triangle
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, imageSize.width, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, imageSize.height / 2);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, imageSize.height / 2); 
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, imageSize.width, 0);
//    CGContextFillPath(context);
  //  CGContextClosePath(context);

    // stroke and fill?
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIGraphicsPopContext();

    return image;    
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I just set the second parameter of UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to YES to make it opaque thinking YUREKA! But alas, this did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer from the following post:
[CGContext line drawing: CGContextFillPath not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808984/cgcontext-line-drawing-cgcontextfillpath-not-working)

One of the last answers provides an example using CGMutablePathRef.  For a triangle, I used the following code:

```
CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, imageSize.width, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 0, imageSize.height / 2);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, imageSize.width, 0);

CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef);

CGContextAddPath(context, pathRef);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextAddPath(context, pathRef);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

CGPathRelease(pathRef);
```

I don't know why the original method I used above does not work however. I will figure that out next.