# Freehand drawing in iOS - Need to use points

Tags: ios, drawing, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

I'm trying to implement freehand drawing on top of an image, but I don't want to save the result as an image. I've adapted code [from this article](http://what-when-how.com/ios-4/drawing-on-a-picture-an-example-ios-4/), but I am not seeing anything draw (though I know the drawRect method is being called). I've verified that I'm iterating through valid CGPoints in the for loop. So everything seems in line, but nothing is physically being drawn.

Am I missing something?

Also, just to note, I've stripped the shape drawing section out, but that is working (drawing ovals, rectangles, and lines).

Here's the code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if( self.shapeType == DrawShapeTypeCustom )
    {
        if( !self.myDrawings )
        {
            self.myDrawings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
        }

        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGFloat red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0, alpha =0.0;
        [[UIColor redColor] getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

        CGContextSetRGBFillColor( ctx , red , green , blue , 0.0 );
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor( ctx , red , green , blue , 0.9 );

        CGContextSetLineWidth( ctx , (CGFloat) 5 );

        if( [self.myDrawings count] > 0 )
        {
            CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx , 5);

            for( int i = 0 ; i < [self.myDrawings count] ; i++ )
            {
                NSArray * array = [self.myDrawings objectAtIndex:i];

                if( [array count] > 2 )
                {
                    CGFloat x = [[array objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
                    CGFloat y = [[array objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];

                    CGContextBeginPath( ctx );
                    CGContextMoveToPoint( ctx , x, y);
                    for( int j = 2 ; j < [array count] ; j+= 2 )
                    {
                        x = [[array objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
                        y = [[array objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];

                        CGContextAddLineToPoint( ctx , x , y );
                    }
                }

                CGContextStrokePath( ctx );
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Draw shapes...
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a `CGMutablePathRef` then adding that to the context and stroking the path then.  I've never done CGContext paths that weren't closed.  Or you could set up an point array and use `CGContextStrokeLineSegments(CGContextRef c, const CGPoint *points, size_t count)`

Comment: It shouldn't be drawing beneath the image. I use common code for creating and adding the subview for both this custom drawing and shape drawing. The shapes show up just fine. I haven't thought about using `CGContextClosePath`, but I actually don't want to close the path. I only want to show the path the user draws. That said, I'll still try it out and see if makes the drawing show up.

Comment: I did think about using line segments, but thought it might look jagged. That said, something is better than nothing right now, so I'll give it a go and see if that helps. If so, and it looks decent, I'll just stick with that. I'll let you know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6800412/1671729  Check that out.  It uses the CGMutablePathRef that I have used in the past.  It seems like exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: check this out. https://github.com/jharwig/SignatureDemo/tree/master/SignatureDemo

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't an `alpha` value of 0 mean that it will be invisible?

Comment: @Garrett, yes, that line can be removed, but it should have no bearing on whether stroke shows up, which is all I care about. Other implementations I was considering included closing the path, and I didn't want a fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for( int j = 2 ; j < [array count] ; j+= 2 )
{
    x = [[array objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
    y = [[array objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];

    CGContextAddLineToPoint( ctx , x , y );
}
```

It looks like you are drawing to the same point over and over again. I guess you should actually use the value of j you're looping through.

```
for( int j = 2 ; j < [array count] ; j+= 2 )
{
    x = [[array objectAtIndex:j + 0] floatValue];
    y = [[array objectAtIndex:j + 1] floatValue];

    CGContextAddLineToPoint( ctx , x , y );
}
```

Comment: Wow, missed that in translation. I was positive I had the points plotting correctly before, but you are absolutely right. Thank you!